# Nullable time.Time

Tags: time, go, null

I have a struct that I intend to populate with a database record, one of the datetime columns is nullable:

```
type Reminder struct {
    Id         int
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    RemindedAt *time.Time
    SenderId   int
    ReceiverId int
}
```

Since pointers can be `nil`, I've made `RemindedAt` a pointer, but this will require the code to know the difference between the `At` variables. Is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: The "." operator works equally well on pointer and non-pointer values.  Why does the code need to "know the difference"?  Do you mean to check if it's nil before using it or...?

Comment: No, if that's true, then what I have works. I assumed I had to handle dereferencing.

Comment: @TobiLehman, in most cases, Go will [dereference pointers to structs](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors), your code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use `pq.NullTime`, or with Go 1.13, you can now use the standard library's [`sql.NullTime`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullTime) type.

From [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/8c6ee72f3e6bcb1542298dd5f76cb74af9742cec/encode.go#L586) on github:

```
type NullTime struct {
    Time  time.Time
    Valid bool // Valid is true if Time is not NULL
}

// Scan implements the Scanner interface.
func (nt *NullTime) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    nt.Time, nt.Valid = value.(time.Time)
    return nil
}

// Value implements the driver Valuer interface.
func (nt NullTime) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    if !nt.Valid {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return nt.Time, nil
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I like the `NullTime` example from lib/pq. I tweaked it this way so the `NullTime` can be treated like a `Time`...

```
type NullTime struct {
    time.Time
    Valid bool
}
```

Answer (score 4):

mysql.NullTime is depricated https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/960
database/sql will have a NullTime type from Go1.13 onward, which should be used instead
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30305

Answer (score 3):

Might also want to check the go-sql-driver implementation, which is basically the same thing as recommended above. https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#NullTime