# Struct embedding with sqlx not returning value from db

Tags: go, sqlx

I have a struct with a time field that may be nil:

```
type Order struct {
    ...
    PickupTime  *time.Time    `json:"-"`
}
```

I want to save this to DB with `sqlx` so I figure I need to use `pq.NullTime` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564619/nullable-time-time-in-golang).

Instead of updating the `Order` object (I don't want to leak DB code into the model layer), I figured I could embedd Order in a `PgOrder` and alter the `PickupTime` type:

```
type PgOrder struct {
    Order
    PickupTime pq.NullTime
}
```

The problem is that when I simply update an `Order` in DB, then turn around and fetch that order, the returned `PickupTime` is empty.

```
// update
func (pg Postgres) UpdateOrderPickupTime(order *Order, pickupTime time.Time) error {
    _, err := pg.Exec(`UPDATE orders SET pickup_time = $1 WHERE id = $2`, pickupTime, order.ID)
    return err
}

// retrieve
func (pg Postgres) GetOrder(orderID DatabaseID) (*Order, error) {
    pgOrder := PgOrder{}
    err := pg.Get(&pgOrder, `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = $1`, orderID)
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        return nil, nil
    }
    ... // at this point pgOrder.PickupTime is 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

}
```

If I put a breakpoint betwen updating and retrieving, I can inspect the DB and see that a value is being saved as `2017-04-20 12:05:37-04`. So the problem must be in the retrieve portion. If I understand right from the [docs](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/#advancedScanning), sqlx should be able to handle embedded structs.

Comment: What is the value in the database itself? `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` looks like it read a zero time from the database--if it had read NULL, I would expect it to be `nil`.

Comment: The value in the DB looks like `2017-04-20 12:05:37-04`

Comment: Just a guess, but did you try changing the order of `PgOrder`'s fields? That is, have the embedded `Order` at the bottom and above it have the `PickupTime pq.NullTime`... e.g. like here: https://play.golang.org/p/_QdVNbWcqS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is a pointer to something, e.g. `*time.Time`, or `*string` you shouldn't need to use the `NullXxx` types. Those types are to be used when you have a non-nil field, e.g. `time.Time`, or `string` while it's corresponding column can be `NULL`.

If you want to ebmed your type anyway, to avoid potential shadowing already mentioned by @Dmitri Goldring, you can to tell `sqlx` to skip the field you don't want it to scan the column into. So just as you did with the `json` tag, you can do so with the `db` tag:

```
type Order struct {
    ...
    PickupTime *time.Time `json:"-" db:"-"`
}

type PgOrder struct {
    Order
    PickupTime pq.NullTime
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're shadowing PickupTime. If I'm reading the sqlx docs right that means it will store the value in the first one it found (in Order) and then when you read the one in PgOrder it's an uninitialized time.Time. You can check the Valid field of PgOrder.PickupTime to confirm this (it should be invalid).