# What is better to use nil or Null* for nullable stuct fields

Tags: database, pointers, go, time, null

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564619/nullable-time-time-in-golang) I saw a question about nullable fields in struct. 
From Go 1.13 you can use [sql.NullTime](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullTime) (earlier declared in `pg` and `mysql`). 
From now we can use these two options to declare the `ResolvedAt` nullable time field:

A. ResolvedAt as NullTime:

```
type Event struct {
    Id         int   
    Resolved   bool
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    ResolvedAt sql.NullTime        
}
```

B. ResolvedAt as pointer:

```
type Event struct {
    Id         int 
    Resolved   bool
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    ResolvedAt *time.Time
}
```

For `Scan` method there is no difference:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM Event")

for rows.Next() {
    e:= new(Event)
    err := rows.Scan(&e.Id, &e.CreatedAt, &e.ResolvedAt)
}
```

But when testing for Null there is a difference:

```
// A. 
e.Resolved = (e.ResolvedAt != nil)  
// B.  
e.Resolved = (e.ResolvedAt.Valid)
```

*In which case is SHOULD to use Null... type rather then pointer?*

Comment: i prefer to use std types so that if i use a library to encode/decode/check an input, that maps straight to the db, it just works. To me the meaning of a pointer within a db struct is rather clear.

Comment: Note also that you can use COALESCE and NULLIF in your queries... It will make the Go code a bit simpler but in turn you'll have to write more sql.

Answer (score 2):

Go lacks [null safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_safety), so this is a workaround. [Null pointers are problematic.](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/) .

By using `sql.NullType` you will get the [Zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) instead of a `Nil` in the scanned field. This fact, when hitting an edge case, could be the difference between panicking or not for your application.

As a rule of thumb, **when in doubt, do not use a pointer.**

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the `sql.Null` types, because it is easier to understand what is going on when reading the code.

If you are using nil pointers it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish by making those fields pointers.