# How to upload a 0 value for not null in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to upload data to a PSQL database and receive the following message:

```
error:
null value in column \"alarm\" violates not-null constraint
```

I've tracked it down to being that the alarm value is 0, not null, but 0... However Golang does not recognize this... Is there a way to get around this quirk?

```
type HsDatum struct {
    ID int64
    UUID uuid.UUID
    HsAssociationID int64
    Timestamp time.Time `sql:",notnull"`
    Value int `sql:",notnull"`
    Alarm int `sql:",notnull"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}


hsDatum := hsdata.HsDatum{
    HsAssociationID: systemAssoc.ID,
    Timestamp: startTime,
    Value: 1,
    Alarm: int(alarm), // 0 in this example
}
```

Added more information about the database logic:

```
func (h *HsDatum) BeforeInsert(db orm.DB) error {
    timeNow := timeutil.TimeNow()
    h.CreatedAt = timeNow
    h.UpdatedAt = timeNow
    // Manage distinct alarm table by checking for new value
    // Note: HS data needs to arrive in chronological order by timestamp
    needsUpdate := false
    lastAlarm, err := hsdistinctalarms.GetHsDistinctAlarmByMostRecent(h.HsAssociationID)
    var timeGap time.Duration
    if database.IsEmptyTable(err) {
        // No values so mark it
        needsUpdate = true
    } else if err == nil {
        if lastAlarm.Alarm != h.Alarm {
            // New value so mark it
            needsUpdate = true
        }
        timeGap = h.Timestamp.Sub(lastAlarm.LastUpdated)
    } else {
        logrus.Errorf("Failed to get most recent distinct alarm: %s", err)
    }
    if needsUpdate {
        // Create new alarm
        newAlarm := hsdistinctalarms.HsDistinctAlarm{
            HsAssociationID: h.HsAssociationID,
            Timestamp:       h.Timestamp,
            Alarm:           h.Alarm,
            LastUpdated:     h.Timestamp,
        }
        err = hsdistinctalarms.CreateHsDistinctAlarm(&newAlarm)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Failed to create hs distinct alarm: %s", err)
        }
    } else {
        // Update timestamp
        lastAlarm.LastUpdated = h.Timestamp
        err = hsdistinctalarms.UpdateHsDistinctAlarm(&lastAlarm)
        if err != nil {
            logrus.Errorf("Failed to update hs distinct alarm: %s", err)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

// CreateHsDatum creates the resource.
// It modifies the parameter in place and returns error information.
func CreateHsDatum(h *HsDatum) error {
    return database.GetDB().Insert(h)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nullable time.Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564619/nullable-time-time)

Comment: @DanielFarrell I don't think that relates to my situation as it is dealing with trying to assign a null value. Not get rid of a null value.

Comment: yeah, okay, it does seem like I had that backwards.  You don't want to have a nullable, but the `Alarm` is attempting to be inserted as a nullable.  Can you show a minimal example of the insert logic?

Comment: @DanielFarrell Updated the post!

Comment: You're using https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kisielk/sqlstruct?tab=doc ?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
 use pointers
e.g.

```
Alarm *int `sql:",notnull"`

...

Alarm: new(int) // init with zero value
or 
Alarm: &alarm   // set a pointer to the alarm variable (should be int)
```

Ugly? Yes.

Option 2:
 use sql.NullInt32
e.g.

```
Alarm sql.NullInt32 `sql:",notnull"`

...
var a sql.NullInt32
if err := a.Scan(alarm); err != nil {
  // handle error
}
...
Alarm: a
...
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as what i said?  But the problem isn't that we need to be able to pass a null, the problem is that we pass a 0 and it trips the not null constraint.  Right, @JordanWx ?

Comment: @Daniel Farrell More or less, yes. But it's solves the actual problem if the `Int32` value within NullInt32 is zero and `Valid` is true.
The main problem here is the marshaller which handles the default value as null. That's why `alarm = 0` behaves like `alarm = null`. (There could be several solution based on the marshaller, but pointers and sql.NullTypes usually solve this problem.